# How can I support special characters in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 5 columns in my SQL Server 2008 table:

```
id INT
name VARCHAR(100)
user address VARCHAR(200)
phone_number VARCHAR(20)
email VARCHAR(50).
```

But I don't know why special characters are not entered on the table.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried **"nvarchar"**. Change the field/fields into nvarchar instead of varchar where you are doubting special characters will come. Or make the table Collation to utf8_general_ci

Comment: No, not amazingly - it's like that by design and [**well documented**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) ...

Answer (score 8):

Use NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR.

> SQL Server provides both datatypes to store character information. For
>   the most part the two datatypes are identical in how you would work
>   with them within SQL Server or from an application. The difference is
>   that nvarchar is used to store unicode data, which is used to store
>   multilingual data in your database tables.