# How to store Spanish text in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, collections

I need to store Spanish text in `SQL` server.

I am using  `varchar` data type for string fields and collation is '`SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`'.

Will it support for Spanish text?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with saving few Spanish text,it is getting saved. But want to make sure that it works with all Spanish characters.

Comment: try nvarchar Datatype

Comment: Is it so difficult to try them all? There can't be that many specifically Spanish characters.

Comment: I don't know Spanish language. Hence could not try all Spanish characters and combinations available

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I support special characters in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497256/how-can-i-support-special-characters-in-sql-server)

Comment: @KV90 - out of curiosity, if you don't know Spanish, how are you going to evaluate any proposed solution's correctness?

Answer (score 2):

Yes u could store in this way :

```
CREATE TABLE #TM(NAME NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO #TM
VALUES(N'El hardware inalámbrico no autorizado se puede introducir fácilmente');
```

Explanation :

> N actually stands for National language character set Which means that you are passing an NCHAR, NVARCHAR or NTEXT value

from Microsoft https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186939.aspx

**Result :**

```
NAME
El hardware inalámbrico no autorizado se puede introducir fácilmente
```

Comment: So the datatype should be NVARCHAR? and why we need to use N before values?

Comment: @KV90 `N` is used to specify that the value is Unicode. For ASCII values, you don't need `N`

Comment: Is it mandatory to pass 'N before values? Do I need to pass 'N if the value is in English?

Comment: @KV90 U could Use N' whenever ur strings have Unicode chars like `ƀ Ɓ Ƃ ƃ Ƅ ƅ Ɔ Ƈ ƈ Ɖ Ɗ Ƌ ƌ ƍ......`